# How do I confirm 1000 Mbps link speed in DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt

Command

> dmesg | grep -i duplex

returns nothing. Version is DD-WRT v3.0-r31100M kongac (01/08/17).

Comment: Why would you expect it to return something?

Comment: My main computer gives 
"eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx"
My nas gives 
"link up, full duplex, speed 1 Gbps"

Comment: Sounds rather different to me.  What is the actual line printed?

Answer (score 3):

You may try `swconfig dev switch0 show` if your router is running on Atheros or Marvell CPU. It works on my *Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH2* running Atheros CPU with firmware *DD-WRT v24SP2-MULTI (06/03/12) std - build 19154*. `swconfig` is not present on router with Broadcom CPU.

It will show output similiar to this.

```
root@LivingRMAP:~# swconfig dev switch0 show
Global attributes:
enable_vlan: 0
Port 0:
mask: 0x004e: (0) 1 2 3 6
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:0 link:down
Port 1:
mask: 0x004d: 0 (1) 2 3 6
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:1 link:up speed:100baseT full-duplex
Port 2:
mask: 0x004b: 0 1 (2) 3 6
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:2 link:up speed:1000baseT full-duplex
Port 3:
mask: 0x0047: 0 1 2 (3) 6
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:3 link:up speed:1000baseT full-duplex
Port 4:
mask: 0x0020: (4) 5
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:4 link:down
Port 5:
mask: 0x0010: 4 (5)
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:5 link:up speed:1000baseT full-duplex
Port 6:
mask: 0x000f: 0 1 2 3 (6)
qmode: 0
pvid: 0
link: port:6 link:up speed:1000baseT full-duplex
```

Comment: root@DD-WRT:~# swconfig dev switch0 show
-sh: swconfig: not found

Comment: I checked on Internet and updated the answer. `swconfig` is only available on router with Atheros or Marvell CPU.

Comment: how to know which port belongs to which eth?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **eth**. The port number is already in the output message, and on your hardware, you can also see the port are numbered as well.

Answer (score 1):

DD-WRT may have different values.  OpenWRT reports the speed in a  `link up` message.  Try a command like `dmesg | grep link`.

If that does not work, try reading the available output with a command like `demsg | more`.